# Mapa aparece branco no app inventor

Tags: android

Eu quero que um mapa apareça na minha app , ja utilizei o codigo html fornecido pela google, ja criei uma api key e ja ativei a api google maps android .
A app vai buscar o ficheiro html ao storage do meu telemovel , passei o ficheiro para o meu computador e abre perfeitamente no internet explorer enquanto no telemovel apenas aparecem botoes de zoom e uma pagina branca.

Comment: Você duplicou esta pergunta. Poderia simplesmente traduzir a outra, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210168/map-in-appinventor-appearing-blank

Comment: N resolveu o meu problema

Comment: Sim, mas não é certo duplicar perguntas porque não obteve respostas. De qualquer forma, deixe esta mesmo, já que a outra está em ingles e será fechada, provavelmente.